# How do I bring the cursor and X/Y intersection to the centre of the screen?

Tags: modeling

How do I bring the cursor and X/Y intersection to the centre of the screen. I asked the question earlier and thanks to D. Dean it only bring the cursor and intersection together but still on the top left corner. Please how do I bring them to the centre of the screen in the object?
[image]

Comment: It is unclear to me what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: I just want the 3D cursor to the centre of the monitor screen. I can move the background image as you can see in centre of the screen. But not the cursor/XY intersection which is still on the top left.

Answer (score 1):

With shift + MiddleMouseButton you can drag the the x- and y-axis + the cursor to the center of your screen. Afterwards your circle and image will still be to the bottom left. Now you can re-center the image as you did before. To center the donout, rightclick on it, click on the + sign in the top right and set the location to x: 0, y:0, z:0

[image]

Comment: @V.Raj164 If this answer helped you, feel free to accept it :)